# How can I increase numeric part of property name in for() loop?

Tags: iphone, xcode, properties, for-loop

I've 10 pan recognisers and want to assign to class property.
How can I increase numeric part of property name in for() loop?

```
for (int i=0; i < [_myArray count]; i++)
{
    myClassInstance.recognizer = pangesture + i ?? // doesn't work of course. but how??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fantastic form — definitely follow Caleb's comments wherever possible — but if you're really backed into a corner:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [_myArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *nameOfProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pangesture%d", i];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recogniser = [self valueForKey:nameOfProperty];
}
```

That's using [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html); `IBOutlet`s are necessarily KVC compliant or there'd be no way to load the NIB.

Answer (score 1):

> I've 10 pan recognisers and want to assign to class property. How can
>   I increase numeric part of property name in for() loop?

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but assuming that you've got 10 gesture recognizers named `g1` through `g10` that you want to assign to 10 objects using a loop, a good approach would be to put those 10 gesture recognizers into an array and then make the assignment using the current index:

```
NSArray *recognizers = @[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10];
if ([recognizers count < [_myArray count]) {
    NSLog("Houston, we have a problem! Not enough gesture recognizers to go around.");
}
for (int i=0; i < [_myArray count]; i++)
{
    myClassInstance.recognizer = recognizers[i]; // note the fancy "new" array access syntax!
}
```

If you're not allocating the gesture recognizers individually, then you can just create one each time though the loop:

```
for (MyClass *instance in _myArray) {
    instance.recognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] init...];
}
```

Comment: yes, but you manually populate recognizers array. I don't want this. I need to put number to property name in for() loop

Comment: how you get g1,g2, g3 in loop?

Comment: @alexhajdu You can't use a variable like a for loop index as part of an identifier, and you shouldn't need to. I used the array literal above because from your question it sounded like you'd already created the gesture recognizers individually. If not, why not just allocate a new gesture recognizer each time through the loop?

Comment: yes, I put recognizer manualy from objects library for each uiimageview and got 10 recognizer outlets with names like panrec0, panrec1, panrec2...is there other way to do that?

Comment: @alexhajdu Could you edit your question to explain more fully what you're trying to accomplish? It's almost always better to use a collection than to use a set of numbered instance variables/outlets/properties. If you want to be able to connect several objects (e.g. recognizers) to a single outlet you can use an `IBOutletCollection`, which can be an mutable array or a mutable set.

Comment: @Caleb -- Actually, you can do this (ignoring the issue of whether you should).  It does take a bit of a tap-dance, though, using the "Runtime Reference" stuff to convert a char string into a selector.  Or use key-value coding.

Comment: @HotLicks You're right, but let's not encourage that sort of thing, shall we? ;-) `s/cant'/shouldn't/` in my first comment.

Comment: tommy got it...thanks caleb for your info, going to teach something about IBOutletCollection and maybe I will create pan recognizers trough the loop

Comment: @Caleb, why it's not ok to use key-value coding?

Comment: @alexhajdu There's nothing wrong with using KVC in general. I was referring more to HotLick's point that you can do this stuff through the runtime. But either way, if what you have is an indexed collection of objects, why screw around with trying to construct a selector name when you can simply use an indexed collection?

Comment: @Caleb it's simple, because I don't know about indexed collection till now :) I'm coding only 2 months in xcode and indexing variable name was known to me so I decide to use it. And how can I create indexed collection from my outlets?

Comment: @alexhajdu "indexed collection" == "array". As mentioned, you can create an outlet that refers to multiple objects using `IBOutletCollection`.